# Xamarin Push Notification

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Receiving and opening notifications with the app in the background increments the number of Data sent.

In addition the notification is not showing when the app is killed or when it is in the foreground.

Below is my code, the source code is from Gerald Versluis https://github.com/jfversluis/XFFCMPushNotificationsSample

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace FCMTest
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();

            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("all");
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += Current_OnTokenRefresh;
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += Current_OnNotificationReceived;
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += Current_OnNotificationOpened;
           //CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationAction += Current_OnNotificationAction;
        }

        private void Current_OnTokenRefresh(object source, FirebasePushNotificationTokenEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Token from function OnTokenRefresh: {e.Token}");
        }

        private void Current_OnNotificationReceived(object source, FirebasePushNotificationDataEventArgs d)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
            foreach (var data in d.Data)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
            }
        }

        /*private void Current_OnNotificationAction(object source, FirebasePushNotificationResponseEventArgs d)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Opened");
            foreach (var data in d.Data)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
            }
        }*/

        private void Current_OnNotificationOpened(object source, FirebasePushNotificationResponseEventArgs d)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Opened");
            foreach (var data in d.Data)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
            }
        }
        
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

```
using FirebaseAdmin;
using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace FCMDispatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("fcm-test-98fe5-firebase-adminsdk-oknwc-c290af4ff0.json")
            });

            // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationToken = "d8yECxIhJXQ:APA91bFGXSrnUVcP07TlN4HpvfstWwEdPQaj4wr6Z3Q-7JqcJJjrFy9LkWdlfzcCNDrZeVy55IDTWxvp5Gfyv8318uRRmIPo6Gp2IQnyUDSHqGLdTF8RMmlwyaECTKWDnmhClMLV8In9";

            // See documentation on defining a message payload.
            var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"myData", "One more try to say Succeded!"},
                    
                },
                Token = registrationToken,
                //Topic = "all",   
                Notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Title = "Test from code",
                    Body = "Here is your test!"
                }
            };

            // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
            // registration token.
            string response = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).Result;
            // Response is a message ID string.
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding priority with high or max to your Data Payload.

```
Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"myData", "One more try to say Succeded!"},
    {"priority", "high"},                   
},
```

This complex condition must match to show your notification:
https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/d86266a9f45687b418f5f1e69c348681d1ff6e27/Plugin.FirebasePushNotification/DefaultPushNotificationHandler.android.cs#L151

Comment: sadly, it didn't fix it

Comment: Ok. Try publish your app in release mode and without attaching a debugger! Sometimes after restarting the emulator/device messaging works. Try this too. If you send message to a topic change `Topic = "all"` to `Topic = "/topics/all"`. If you still receive no messages, please post your complete MainActivity and Application Code.